# How do I insert rows in a table with different select sub queries in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add multiple rows to a table in just one query and some of the values that I want to insert come from different tables. How do I do that? Here's the idea of the sql statement I'm trying to put together:

```
INSERT INTO 
    finalTable (oneID, twoID, oneName, twoNAme, formValue) 
VALUES 
     ('1','a', SELECT oneName FROM tableOne WHERE id = '1' , SELECT twoName FROM tableTwo WHERE id = 'a', 'some value'),
     ('2','b', SELECT oneName FROM tableOne WHERE id = '2' , SELECT twoName FROM tableTwo WHERE id = 'b' ,'some other value')
```

the select sub-queries are not working in this format, how do I re-write the statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.this might work for your scenario.

INSERT INTO 
    finalTable (oneID, twoID, oneName, twoNAme, formValue)

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT T1.id,T2.Id,T1.oneName,T2.twoName, 'some value' FROM tableOne T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tableTwo T2 ON T2.id>0 WHERE T1.id = '1' AND T2.id='a' LIMIT 1) A

 UNION
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT T1.id,T2.Id,T1.oneName,T2.twoName, 'some other value' FROM tableOne T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tableTwo T2 ON T2.id>0 WHERE T1.id = '2' AND T2.id='b'  LIMIT 1) B
```